# How can I change my code so that string is NOT changed to float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to write a code that detects fake news. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error message. Please could someone explain where I've gone wrong? I have got some lines of codes from https://data-flair.training/blogs/advanced-python-project-detecting-fake-news/ and some lines of code from https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/text-analytics-beginners-nltk. When I tried to combine the two different codes (by getting rid of duplicate codes), I receive an error message.

**THE CODE**

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import itertools
import json
import csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier  
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\johnrambo\Downloads\fake_news(1).csv", sep=',', header=0, engine='python', escapechar='\\')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['headline'], is_sarcastic_1, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 7)

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)

predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

print("MultinomialNB Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted))
```

---

**THE ERROR**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e1f11a702626> in <module>
     21 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['headline'], is_sarcastic_1, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 7)
     22 
---> 23 clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
     24 
     25 predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    586         self : object
    587         """
--> 588         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
    589         _, n_features = X.shape
    590 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    717                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    718                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 719                     estimator=estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    946             warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=3)
    947             dtype = "M8[ns]"
--> 948         return np.asarray(self.array, dtype)
    949 
    950     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\numpy_.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    164 
    165     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
--> 166         return np.asarray(self._ndarray, dtype=dtype)
    167 
    168     _HANDLED_TYPES = (np.ndarray, numbers.Number)

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'experts caution new car loses 90% of value as soon as you drive it off cliff'
```

---

FIRST FEW LINES OF DATA

[Excel file: fake news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgyG0.png)

***This is what I get when I input df.head().to_dict() :***

{'is_sarcastic': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'headline': {0: 'thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock of hair loss',
  1: 'dem rep. totally nails why congress is falling short on gender, racial equality',
  2: 'eat your veggies: 9 deliciously different recipes',
  3: 'inclement weather prevents liar from getting to work',
  4: "mother comes pretty close to using word 'streaming' correctly"},
 'article_link': {0: 'https://www.theonion.com/thirtysomething-scientists-unveil-doomsday-clock-of-hai-1819586205',
  1: 'https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/donna-edwards-inequality_us_57455f7fe4b055bb1170b207',
  2: 'https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/eat-your-veggies-9-delici_b_8899742.html',
  3: 'https://local.theonion.com/inclement-weather-prevents-liar-from-getting-to-work-1819576031',
  4: 'https://www.theonion.com/mother-comes-pretty-close-to-using-word-streaming-cor-1819575546'}}

Comment: Please share your data as `df.head().to_dict()` and try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: What kinds of input does `MultinomialNB().fit` expect (numpy array, dtype, shape)?  Check the same attributes for `X_train`, `y_train`.

Comment: Hello rpanai, I have edited my post to show what shows up when I add the code df.head().to_dict().

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have text data in `df['headline']` column, you need a few steps to first convert the text data to a number based format, then pass it to machine learning models to handle.

You might want to refer to sklearn's `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Comment: Yes, I have text data in the 'headline' column. Both attributes are text, only the label is a binary 0 or 1 (i.e. yes or no). I take your point about sklearn's two classes.